# Basic php code within a page

Tags: php

If i have a file called `file.php` and want to display 3 different contents in it.  one would you regular `file.php` and the other 2 would be `file.php?c=1` `file.php?c=2`

How can I go about doing that?

Example

```
<html>
<head>
   ...........

<body>

something goes here 1 <show only if "link.com/file.php?c=1 or file.php"

something goes here 2 <show only if "link.com/file.php?c=2

something goes here 3 <show only if "link.com/file.php?c=3    



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `if( $_GET[ 'c' ] == 1 ) ...`

Comment: please clarify what you are asking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if( !isset($_GET[ 'c' ] ) ){
    # perform file.php actions
} else if( $_GET[ 'c' ] == 1 ) {
    # perform file.php?c=1 actions
} else if( $_GET[ 'c' ] == 2 ) {
    # perform file.php?c=2 actions
}
```

The first condition checks if there is a `querystring` for the paremeter `c`. If there isn't then you have your file.php regular actions. The second and third will let you know that you have a parameter c and perform whatever actions you set if the value is 1 or 2

Without the `!isset(...` check you may get an error like this:

```
Notice:  Undefined index: c
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// $c defaults to 1, if &c=xxx is specified, $c will be intval($_GET['c'])    
$c = isset($_GET['c']) ? intval($_GET['c']) : 1;

if ($c == 1) {
    require('f1.php');
} else if ($c == 2) {
    require('f2.php');
} ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!isset($_REQUEST['c'])){
    require_once(file.php);
}
else if(isset($_REQUEST['c'])==1){
   require_once(file1.php);
}
else if(isset($_REQUEST['c'])==2){
   require_once(file2.php);
}
```

//Now you can use according to your requirement and conditions this will work.